# Does 1 Corinthians 15 & 2 Maccabees 12 reflect a belief in both the sacrificial nature of the Eucharist, as well as a belief in 'purgatory'?

Tags: 1-corinthians, sacrifice, eucharist, 2-maccabees

**Question:** Since Christians went on to **offer the Eucharist on for the dead,**<sup>1</sup> is it tenable, *based on 1 Corinthians, namely the portion cited below,* to see *1 Corinthians* in particular **as a reference** to this practice from St. Paul's time?

---

What made me think this, are parallels I discovered while reading *1 Cortinthians*, to the (Greek Old Testament) book of *2 Maccabees,* where sacrifice is offered for the dead and a collection taken for said purpose:

> **2 Maccabees 12:38-46 [DRB](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2+Maccabees+12%3A38-46&version=DRA)**
>
> So Judas [Maccabeus] having gathered together his army, came into the city Odollam: and when the seventh day came, they purified themselves according to the custom, and kept the sabbath in the place. And the day following Judas came with his company, to take away the bodies of them that were slain, and to bury them with their kinsmen, in the sepulchres of their fathers. And they found under the coats of the slain some of the donaries of the idols of Jamnia, which the law forbiddeth the Jews: so that all plainly saw, for this cause they were slain. Then they all blessed the just judgment of the Lord, who had discovered the things that were hidden. And so **betaking themselves to prayers,** they besought him, that **the sin which had been committed might be forgotten.** [cf. Mt 12:32b] But the most valiant Judas **exhorted the people to keep themselves from sin,** forasmuch as they saw before their eyes what had happened, because of the sins of those that were slain. And **making a collection, he sent twelve thousand drachmas of silver to Jerusalem for sacrifice to be offered for the sins of the dead,** [cf. Bar 1:6-7,10] thinking well and religiously concerning the resurrection, **(For *if he had not hoped that they that were slain should rise again, it would have seemed superfluous and vain to pray for the dead,)*** And because he considered that they who had **fallen asleep with godliness**, had great **grace** *laid up for them*. It is therefore a holy and wholesome thought to *pray for the dead*, that they may be loosed from sins.

---

> **1 Corinthians 15:16-18,29,34; 16:1-3 [DRB](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Corinthians+15%3A16-16%3A3&version=DRA)** (arbitrary chapter division)
>
> For if the dead rise not again, neither is Christ risen again. And if Christ be not risen again, your faith is vain, for you are yet in your sins. Then they also that are **fallen asleep in Christ**, are perished. ... Otherwise what shall they do that are baptized for the dead,<sup>2</sup> ***if the dead rise not again at all? why are they then baptized for them?*** ... **Awake, ye just, and sin not.** For some have not the knowledge of God, I speak it to your shame.
>   ...
>   Now concerning **the collections that are made for the saints,** as I have given order to the churches of Galatia, so do ye also. On the first day of the week let every one of you put apart with himself, **laying up** what it shall well please him; that when I come, the collections be not then to be made. And when I shall be with you, whomsoever you shall approve by letters, them will I send to **carry your grace to Jerusalem.** And if it be meet that I also go, they shall go with me.

---

### Summary

Does 1 Corinthians show that St. Paul or Christians offered a sacrifice (the only I can think of is the Eucharist, whose offering indeed involves costs: the wage of the priest,<sup>3</sup> as well as the Eucharistic elements, bread and wine)? Which is to say: are we or are we not to see St. Paul as making reference to the same practice of offering something (perhaps the Eucharist, based on subsequent Christian writings) for the dead, including even a collection, or not; and **if not, why not, (i.e. the exegetical/contextual reasons)** and vice versa.

---

Thank you in advance!

---

<sup>**Footnotes**</sup>

<sup>**1** E.g.  St. Cyril, *[On the Mysteries V., 6-9.](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf207.ii.xxvii.html?highlight=7,8,9#highlight)* (Cat. Lect. 23). cf. Concil. Trid. [Sess. XXII,](http://www.thecounciloftrent.com/ch22.htm) cap. 2.</sup>

<sup>**2** 1Cor 15:30 "we"—that is, not only the church at Corinth, but Christians as a whole maintain the practice—that is, if 'baptism for the dead' is the first in an iteration (*τί καὶ*) of examples of spiritual hardship. cf. 15:31b. 'Baptism' hereseems to refer to metaphorical baptism of spiritual hardship, not water baptism. See *Lk 12:50; Mk 10:38; Mt 20:22*.</sup>

<sup>**3** i.e. the sole income source for priests. cf. *1 Cor 9:14*.</sup>

Comment: I've voted to close as Too Broad. What specific text are we supposed to exegete? (The whole chapter of 1 Cor 15? Second Macc 12? Both?) Given that 1 Cor 15 never even mentions the Eucharist (not the bread, not the wine, not the meal), and barely discusses the death of Jesus (not even as 'sacrificial'), I am skeptical of the assumptions being made (such as whether Paul is alluding to 2 Macc). I think to narrow down the question and give it sharp focus, it should ask *if* Paul is alluding to 2 Macc.

Comment: My question is quite narrow, I believe: are there reasons to reject the thesis given (which is to say, is there "validity [in] seeing *1 Corinthians 15* [specifically the portion quoted] as supporting the concepts (or reflecting the beliefs in said concepts) above, *in consideration of* 2 Maccabees 12, on a purely textual basis"). This necessarily **includes the possibility that there is no connection at all.** However, such an answer might show how this is unlikely or untenable, or provide an alternative explanation for the apparent ("seems") allusion to a certain practice.

Comment: The practice of praying for the dead is not tantamount to a belief in purgatory.  Purgatory is a Roman Catholic doctrine that was/is rejected by the eastern Church, even though the eastern Church does pray for the dead (Cyril was Patriarch of Jerusalem, one of the four eastern Sees).

Comment: Is your thesis that Paul was collecting money to pay for sacrifices that would be offered for Christians who had died in Jerusalem?

Comment: @user33515  Do they pray for dead saints or dead sinners?

Comment: @user3.. I gave a particular/minimal definition of purgatory (which is not at odds with 'Orthodoxy'/2Macc) to avoid these kind of doctrinal disagreements. *Prayer for* implies need or relief (not yet in heaven; can be helped). +Rum. Yes, if by "Christians who have died" ("saints")you mean they are the recipients of the grace accrued by the offering made (at Jers.). It just looks *an awful lot* like what Christians went on to/continued to do for the dead (using Cyr. as a quick example, esp. since he was bishop of Jerusalem). Namely, offer the Eucharist for themselves and the dead/pray for them.

Comment: I do see the general allusion to 2 Macc but (as I've seen with Wisdom of Solomon) not the specifics. Are we talking about indulgences? Raising money to have the priests intercede to move them on from limbo by praying for them at a "Eucharist" altar, for the forgiveness of their sins?

Comment: @Ruminator We are only talking about helping 'loose' departed saints from the 'purgatorial' state before they are admitted to heaven. The collection is probably, according to the thesis, just like what happens today: the congregation might raise funds to have the sacrifice of the Eucharist offered by the priest on behalf of some departed "saint" (convention was to call all Christian saints, since that was their calling, but what we would now call 'holy souls').The coll. might have been a combin. of the costs of the Euch. elem. and the partial wage of the priest (cf. 1 Cor 9:14).

Comment: I don't think that putting a word in quotes to signify something other than the widely understood meaning of what is quoted is particularly useful.  Purgatory is well understood in the west as a place (whether one believes in the place or not) where souls undergo punishment that somehow "purges" them from certain sins before they can enter heaven.  If you want to confine the discussion to beliefs regarding praying for the dead in general, there is no sense I think in introducing such a loaded term into the discussion.  In any case, the question has been closed for being too broad ....

Comment: ... I do think it would be interesting, though, to open separate discussions on the two topics.  They may end up being more suitable, though, for Christianity SE and not hermeneutics.

Comment: I became aware of such shortly after 'launching' the question. I disagree that the modern understanding of purgatory is at odds with my particular definition (which was only for the sake of simplifying the question—imagine citing some official definition!) I tried to keep it purely textual.The physicality or not of the spiritual abode is as open as with Hell. But 'loosed from their sins' can only be people, namely the souls thereof ('holy souls,' as we now call them), who are not yet loosed from their sins (not in heaven)—I'm not aware of a definition of purgatory which goes beyond this.

Comment: Perhaps the thing to do is to simplify the question by removing any reference to purgatory and just focus on the allusion and sacrificial angle.

Answer (score 1):

I won't repeat the citing and highlighting done in the original question but there does seem to be a formal allusion to the 2 Maccabees passage in the 1 Corinthians 15 passage. Unlike most of the intertextuality of the scriptures the allusion seems only to form rather than to substance such as we see often in the Wisdom of Solomon. For example, see this post of mine:

[Is Romans 1:18-23 alluding to Wisdom of Solomon 13?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/30108/is-romans-118-23-alluding-to-wisdom-of-solomon-13)

There is no appeal to the former for the authority of the latter and only a loose connection to the subject matter and not much that looks like an actual quote. I'm not even sure if it isn't intended to correct the passage it alludes to rather than appeal to it in any way.

I can see two possible explanations for the coincidence of Paul's Jerusalem offering vis a vis Judas Maccabee's:

- Paul is consciously associating his gathering of offerings for the poor of Jerusalem with the noble and venerated actions of Judas described in what he and his audience recognized as scripture to demonstrate its legitimacy
- the passage is a later addition by unscrupulous clergy hoping to have money directed to themselves

Both seem possible to me. The latter particularly so given that much of 1 Cor 11 appears to be an addition.

What doesn't seem possible to me is that Paul was collecting money for sacrifices or for paying for prayers for paid priests to move saints from purgatory into Heaven. All of that is so foreign to Paul's writings and spirit as to be rejected out of hand. For example, paid priests?! Paul often solicited prayers but never for the dead. Never paid prayers. And he knew nothing of a "Eucharist". If that is what Paul was on about I'm off to Mecca or to visit Da Buddha or something!

As to the appeal to Hebrews 13:10, the "altar" that he refers to is the place of Jesus' execution, "outside the camp" where praise to God, professing Christ, doing good and sharing with others is to be done. He places this in contradistinction to ceremonial eating:

> NIV Hebrews 13: 9**Do not be carried away by all kinds of strange
>   teachings. It is good for our hearts to be strengthened by grace, not
>   by eating ceremonial foods, which is of no benefit to those who do so.
>   10We have an altar from which those who minister at the tabernacle
>   have no right to eat.** 11The high priest carries the blood of animals
>   into the Most Holy Place as a sin offering, but the bodies are burned
>   outside the camp. 12And so Jesus also suffered outside the city gate
>   to make the people holy through his own blood. 13Let us, then, go to
>   him outside the camp, bearing the disgrace he bore. 14For here we do
>   not have an enduring city, but we are looking for the city that is to
>   come.
>   **15Through Jesus, therefore, let us continually offer to God a sacrifice of praise—the fruit of lips that openly profess his name.
>   16And do not forget to do good and to share with others, for with such
>   sacrifices God is pleased.**

Re-sacrificing Christ weekly is also specifically rejected:

> Hebrews 9: 24For Christ did not enter a sanctuary made with human
>   hands that was only a copy of the true one; he entered heaven itself,
>   now to appear for us in God’s presence. 25Nor did he enter heaven to
>   offer himself again and again, the way the high priest enters the Most
>   Holy Place every year with blood that is not his own. 26Otherwise
>   Christ would have had to suffer many times since the creation of the
>   world. But he has appeared once for all at the culmination of the ages
>   to do away with sin by the sacrifice of himself. 27Just as people are
>   destined to die once, and after that to face judgment, 28so Christ was
>   sacrificed once to take away the sins of many; and he will appear a
>   second time, not to bear sin, but to bring salvation to those who are
>   waiting for him.

That the "Eucharist" or "Mass" or "Divine Liturgy" as it is variously called is conceived of as a re-sacrificing of the Christ each time is evidenced in the prayer:

> ...The congregation, which has been seated during this preparatory
>   rite, rises, and the priest gives an exhortation to pray: "Pray,
>   brethren, that my sacrifice and yours may be acceptable to God, the
>   almighty Father." The congregation responds: "May the Lord accept the
>   sacrifice at your hands, for the praise and glory of his name, for our
>   good, and the good of all his holy Church." The priest then pronounces
>   the variable prayer over the gifts...
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_the_Catholic_Church

Also, in appealing to 2 Maccabees, where sacrifices were paid for by Judas on behalf of the living and the dead by priests authorized to make the sacrifices the whole thing is a repackaging of the Jewish sacrificial system. This misconstrues the death of Jesus as a sacrifice rather than as a ratifying death of the new covenant made between God and the houses of Israel and Judah:

> NIV Hebrews 10 1The law is only a shadow of the good things that are
>   coming—not the realities themselves. For this reason it can never, by
>   the same sacrifices repeated endlessly year after year, make perfect
>   those who draw near to worship. 2**Otherwise, would they not have
>   stopped being offered? For the worshipers would have been cleansed
>   once for all, and would no longer have felt guilty for their sins.
>   3But those sacrifices are an annual reminder of sins.** 4It is
>   impossible for the blood of bulls and goats to take away sins.
>
> 5Therefore, when Christ came into the world, he said:
>
> **“Sacrifice and offering you did not desire**, but a body you prepared
>   for me; 6**with burnt offerings and sin offerings you were not pleased.**
>   7Then I said, ‘Here I am—it is written about me in the scroll— I have
>   come to do your will, my God.’ ” 8**First he said, “Sacrifices and
>   offerings, burnt offerings and sin offerings you did not desire, nor
>   were you pleased with them”**—though they were offered in accordance
>   with the law [which the mass is not]. 9Then he said, “Here I am, I
>   have come to do your will.” He sets aside the first [covenant] to
>   establish the second [covenant]. 10And by that will [the setting aside
>   of the first covenant and establishment of the new covenant], we [the
>   elect of the houses of Israel and Judah] have been made holy through
>   the sacrifice [ratifying death] of the body of Jesus Christ **once for all.**
>   11**Day after day every priest stands and performs his religious duties;
>   again and again he offers the same sacrifices, which can never take
>   away sins. 12But when this priest had offered for all time one
>   sacrifice for sins, he sat down at the right hand of God, 13and since
>   that time he waits for his enemies to be made his footstool. 14For by
>   one sacrifice he has made perfect forever those who are being made
>   holy.**
>
> 15The Holy Spirit also testifies to us about this. First he says:
>   16“This is the covenant I will make with them [the houses of Israel
>   and Judah] after that time, says the Lord. I will put my laws in their
>   hearts, and I will write them on their minds.” 17Then he adds:
>   **“Their sins and lawless acts I will remember no more.” 18And where these have > been forgiven, sacrifice for sin is no longer necessary.**

Jesus said the same:

> New Living Translation 1 Corinthians 11:25 In the same way, he took
>   the cup of wine after supper, saying, "This cup is the new covenant
>   between God and his people [the Jews]--an agreement confirmed with my
>   blood. Do this to remember me as often as you drink it."

That the covenant/testament, like the Sinai covenant was made exclusively with the elect Jews and why is repeated in the terms of the covenant itself:

> 31“The days are coming,” declares the Lord, “when I will make a new
>   covenant
>   **with the people of Israel and with the people of Judah.** 32It will **not be like the covenant I made with their ancestors when I took them by the hand to lead them out of Egypt, because they broke my
>   covenant, though I was a husband tod them**, ” declares the Lord.
>   33“This is the covenant I will make **with the people of Israel**
>   after that time,” declares the Lord. “I will put my law in their minds
>   and write it on their hearts. I will be their God, and **they will be
>   my people**. 34No longer will they teach their neighbor, or say to one
>   another, ‘Know the Lord,’ because they will all know me, from the
>   least of them to the greatest,” declares the Lord. “For I will forgive
>   their wickedness and will remember their sins no more.” 35This is what
>   the Lord says,
>
> he who appoints the sun to shine by day, who decrees the moon and
>   stars to shine by night, who stirs up the sea so that its waves roar—
>   the Lord Almighty is his name: 36**“Only if these decrees vanish from
>   my sight,” declares the Lord, “will Israel ever cease being a nation
>   before me.”** declares the Lord. 37This is what the Lord says:
>
> **“Only if the heavens above can be measured and the foundations of the earth below be searched out will I reject all the descendants of
>   Israel because of all they have done,”**
>
> NIV Hebrews 8:
>   **7For if there had been nothing wrong with that first covenant, no place would have been sought for another. 8But God found fault with
>   the people and said : “The days are coming, declares the Lord, when I
>   will make a new covenant with the people of Israel and with the people
>   of Judah. 9It will not be like the covenant I made with their
>   ancestors when I took them by the hand to lead them out of Egypt,
>   because they did not remain faithful to my covenant, and I turned away
>   from them,** declares the Lord.
>   **10This is the covenant I will establish with the people of Israel** after that time, declares the Lord. I will put my laws in their minds
>   and write them on their hearts. I will be their God, and they will be
>   my people. 11No longer will they teach their neighbor, or say to one
>   another, ‘Know the Lord,’ because they will all know me, from the
>   least of them to the greatest. 12For I will forgive their wickedness
>   and will remember their sins no more.” 13By calling this covenant
>   “new,” he has made the first one obsolete; and what is obsolete and
>   outdated will soon disappear.
>
> NIV Hebrews 9:15 15For this reason Christ is the mediator of a new
>   covenant, that those who are called [the elect Jews - see Romans 9]
>   may receive the promised eternal inheritance—now that he has died as a
>   ransom **to set them free from the sins committed under the first
>   covenant**.

Comment: I've upvoted this otherwise good answer, however, two points in particular prevent me from marking it as an answer (I was looking for the more critical anyway bec. I'm nterested in the validity of the conn.), and those are the manifestly false: *"And he knew nothing of a "Eucharist"* and *"Re-sacrificing Christ weekly"*. Nowhere in Christians history is Mass/Divine Liturgy (all referring to the Eucharistic sacrifice) considered or intended to be a RE sacrifice. in fact, it is explicitly identified as not such, and instead a presentation on the altar of that one and same sacrifice of Calvary.

Comment: As for Heb 13's (you made a typo 'Romans' instead of Heb) altar, I concede that it can validly be understood as one of offering praise, that is, metaphorical (however 9 and 10 in light of the fact of the Eucharist celebration, which was 100% ceremonial foods, this may denote a contrast). I don't think the same can be said of 1 Cor 10:16:29; 11:28-29 and other passages, especially in light of their perennial interpretation etc.

Comment: "is conceived of as a re-sacrificing of the Christ..evidenced in the prayer" You can't use this nor really any prayer as a proof of what people believe, in ignorance of what it is they in fact do CCC1368. As someone who reads this prayer every Sunday from the missal, I know that nowhere is the sacrifice said to be an other than the same of Calvary, as the Church teaches.It is the re-presentation of the same sac. Ex24:5,8;Mt26:28; 1Co11:24 not a re-sacrificing. Your re-interpretation of passages concerning the Eucharist, Jesus' death as a sacrifice etc are far too off base for me to respond to!

Comment: Is there a quick answer, link to explain why the Maccabees were removed from the Bible, and kept out?