# Did Solomon write Wisdom of Solomon?

Tags: authorship, solomon, wisdom-of-solomon, provenance

In addition to Proverbs there are other canonical texts that non-scholars tend to attribute to Solomon of more dubious origin.

What evidence is there that Wisdom of Solomon alleges to have been written by Solomon?

If so, is that credible? If so, what evidence is there?

See related:  [Did Solomon write Song of Solomon?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/34184/did-solomon-write-song-of-solomon)

Comment: Somewhat related: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/30108/is-romans-118-23-alluding-to-wisdom-of-solomon-13?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authorship of the Wisdom books is even more obscure that the so-called Solomonic literature.  If we accept that Solomon was real historical figure of the 10th Cent BC (as I do) then he could not have written the Wisdom of Solomon because it was clearly composed in Greek and dependant on Isaiah, the Septuagint and the OT pseudepigrapha (eg Enoch, et al) at that!

Comment: It may be fallacious to assume not a common tradition underlying both Enoch and Wisdom (although you cited no instance of alleged dependancy), but that Wisodm 'depends' on Enoch—at least as a cited proof of its post-dating these.. Likewise that Septuagintic translation philosophies were not known or adopted by those before the later Septuagint translation proper: the Septuagint could have adopted Wisdom-esque Hebrew-to-Greek translation, for example, rather than vice versa. (Although, I do tend to agree it is a later work and Greek original; I may research for an answer of my own soon.)

Comment: I agree with your comments.  My poorly worded answer was intended to convey that its composition in Greek excluded Solomonic authorship and that was confirmed (not proved) by its numerous similarities with other sources.  However, I also agree it is far too late and its style is clearly Hellenistic not Hebraic.